# Nest for elasticsearch 2.1.1 version

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

What version of NEST should i use for latest Elasticsearch version (2.1.1). We are planning to release our product in another 2 months and we are releasing with Elasticsearch 2.1.1 and wanted to know the right version of NEST to use

Comment: This should help: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/2.0.0-alpha1

Answer (score 2):

Nest has currently released version `2.0.0-alpha1` which should be compatible with Elasticsearch 2.x. I'm not sure when they will make Nest 2.0 generally available. You can download the pre-release version from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NEST/2.0.0-alpha1).

Comment: There are now milestones within the github repo: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/milestones